# Nuxt 3 change layout when on mobile

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

So I just started A Nuxt 3 app (with ssr turned off) and I am trying to change the layout when I am on a mobile device. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xh_OrVwgh4M.

The thing is I am using nuxt 3, so it's a bit different. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

In the tutorial ha defined his middleware in the config but I did it like this; I have made in my `middleware` folder a `mobile.global.ts` with the following code:

```
export default function(context: { isMobile: boolean; }){
    let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    context.isMobile = /mobile/i.test(userAgent)
}
```

And this is what I have in my `index.vue`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

definePageMeta({
    layout: ({isMobile}) =>  isMobile ? "mobile" : "default",
})

</script>
```

This is the warning that I am getting:

```
valid layout `({ isMobile }) => isMobile ? "mobile" : "default"` selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability, I would recommend using [Device module](https://nuxt.com/modules/device#change-a-layout-dynamically) which does the middleware stuff you are trying to do automatically.

On your question. This isn't how you define [middleware](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware) in nuxt 3.
You use `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {...})` for that.

I would first define a middleware like this.

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
let userAgent = process.server
    ? useRequestHeaders()["user-agent"]
    : navigator.userAgent
to.params.isMobile = String(/mobile/i.test(userAgent))
})
```

And then access the isMobile parameter in the page file like this.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const layout = useRoute().params.isMobile == "true" ? "mobile" : "desktop"
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLayout :name="layout">
    whatever
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Now, I wouldn't recommend the second option. + I would use a reactive value rather than untyped isMobile parameter. + I wouldn't put this logic in every page, but in the *layout itself*

Answer (score 0):

I do a simple Javascript conditional to see if it is a mobile-like viewport width via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth .

```
onMounted(() => {
  const isMobileViewport = window.innerWidth >= 1024 ? true : false
...
}
```

If you're doing SSR, only do this within `onMounted` or check for `window` property. This example does not update true/false on the fly if the viewport is adjusted, but I generally don't like to watch for viewport, scroll, mouse changes.